# How to translate content page in a master page after language change (ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, translation

I have a content page in a master page in ASP.NET.
What is going on is that the user click on a button in the right corner of the master page and that change the current language. What does the button is changing the Session for the new selected language.

What is happening is that when you click on a button, the code is executed AFTER the Page_Load of both the master page and the content page is called. But in my button, I call a function "Translate" that do the translation of the master page.

Unfortunately, I don't know what to do for the content page. I tried to do a manual reload of it but I don't know how.

Is there anyone here that can help me? I don't think that code is needed here but if it can help you, just ask me what you need and I will update.

Thanks

Jaff

Answer (score 0):

After changing the users language settings (both on the thread and where ever you persist that information too) do a Response.Redirect to the page they are already on.  This allows for a clean page load and reduces the chance that other culture specific settings will cause a problem (such as date and time selections.)